# Square root of 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was watching some videos on algebra and found someone said that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}
$$

$$= \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}
$$

Can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: Multiply the top and bottom of the first fraction by $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: And finally $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}=2^{1/2}\cdot 2^{1/2} = 2^{1/2 + 1/2} = 2$.

Comment: √2 x √2 = 2  so √2 x √2 / 2  = 1 so √2 / 2 = 1 / √2   - by rearranging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well:

$$1=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2}$$

Now:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Answer (score 8):

Since $\sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 2 = 2$:

$$\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} = \frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

*More direct:*
$$\sqrt2\cdot\frac{\sqrt2}2=\frac{\bigl(\sqrt2\bigr)^2}{2}=\frac22=1,$$
so by definition $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}2$ is the reciprocal of $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=2^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sqrt{2})=(2^{-1}\cdot2^{\frac{1}{2}})=2^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more generally, $\sqrt{2}=2^{\frac{1}{2}}$, and $2=2^1$, thus, $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2^1}=2^{\frac{1}{2}-1}=2^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$